# How to random an array so that a value should be printed x% at a time?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am trying to make a simple slot machine in java. However I do not know how to randomize the array so that the a certain value of an array will return for x% at a time.

For example for the code below, I want to randomize the result given that Fish will return 40% , Dragon will return 30%, Joke will return 25% and Jackpot will return 5% at a time.

```java
public class SlotMachine{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String array[] = {"Fish", "Dragon", "Joker", "Jackpot"};    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just generate a random number between 0 and 1 and then choose an array element according your desired logic:

```
double rand = Math.random();
String choice;
if (rand < 0.05) {
    choice = array[3];
}
else if (rand < 0.30) {
    choice = array[2];
}
else if (rand < 0.60) {
    choice = array[1];
}
else {
    choice = array[0];
}

System.out.println(choice);
```

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry!!! I didn't read the question carefully enough. Just ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import java.util.Random

public class SlotMachine{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String array[] = {"Fish", "Dragon", "Joker", "Jackpot"};
    Random rand = new Random();

    // Obtain a number between [0 - 100].
    if (rand.nextInt(100) <= 40) System.out.print('Fish ')
    if (rand.nextInt(100) <= 30) System.out.print('Dragon ')
    if (rand.nextInt(100) <= 25) System.out.print('Joker')
    if (rand.nextInt(100) <= 5) System.out.print('Jackpot')
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding this answer, so you are suggesting that I randomize a number and if the number is less than or equal to 40 , The result will be Fish . And so on. My question is what if the randomized number will have a result of 50 ? so none of them will be printed right? but in my program, It needs to return a value but the value to be returned will be based on percentages. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: you are right, I was'nt sure how you are going to implement the slot machine, I just wanted to give you a general idea as for how to randomize with fixed probabilities as you mentioned and the way you can use `Random.nextint()` for that, so it was mainly my misunderstanding of your question.